# Dynamically add value to tinymce custom toolbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tinymce, tinymce-5

I have created a custom toolbar in TinyMCE and have a list of values to display on it. When I click a button, I need to dynamically add a value to the list on the custom toolbar. I have tried the below method but it is not getting added to the dropdown list.

Link to the fiddle: https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/Pqfaab/90

I wanted to check if there is any way to add it to a list?"

```
<script src='http://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js'></script>
<script>
 var tempGroups = ['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4'];

 var tempGroupName;
 var menuItems = [];
 
 function addToGroup(e){
    console.log("sdfsf");
    e.preventDefault();
    tempGroups.push('Group 5');
 }

 function createTempMenu(editor) {
   for (i = 0; i < tempGroups.length; i++) {
     tempGroupName = tempGroups[i];
     menuItems[i] = {
       text: tempGroupName,
       menu: tempGroups
     };
   }
   return menuItems;
 }

  tinymce.init({
    selector: '#mytextarea',
    toolbar1: 'UseTemplates',
    setup: function(editor) {
     editor.addButton('UseTemplates', {
       type: 'menubutton',
       text: 'usetemplates',
       icon: false,
       menu: createTempMenu(editor)
     });
   }
  });
  </script>


<h1>Custom Properties for Toolbar Buttons and Menu items</h1>
  <form method="post">
    <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
    <button onclick="addToGroup(event)">Add to Group</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're creating the menu when the editor is initiated. The array used when creating the button didn't include "Group 5".
You should make some "onclick" event on click on the menu to create the menu so it always use the updated array.